# Is there a way to return created record without querying into database again?

Tags: c#, mysql, database, orchardcms

```
var q = this._prometnaPozivnicaRepository.Table
            .Where(x => x.SenderId == userId && 
                        x.Namjena == namjena && 
                       (x.DateExpire > DateTime.UtcNow || x.ReceiverId > 0))
            .ToList();

MyRecord record = new PrometnaPozivnicaRecord
{
    CiklusId = 0,
    Namjena = namjena,
    SenderId = userId,
    ReceiverId = 0,
    DateSent = datumOd,
    DateExpire = datumDo
};

this._prometnaPozivnicaRepository.Create(record);
q.Add(pozivnica);
return q;
```

The thing is that the field called "Kod" creates on the database,and it is a property from MyRecord. As you can see that I create the record than insert it into my db table. When I create it, my database automatically assigns value to the Kod field.

Is there any way to return created record instantly without querying into db table again?

Comment: One way or another you will have to query the database, some ORMs such as Entity Framework will do this sort of thing automatically but behind the scenes it will run 2 queries.

Comment: This is NHibernate ORM I think

Comment: You think? Don't you know what technology you are using?

Comment: Orchard uses NHibernate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `IRepository.Create()` calls NHibernate `ISession.Save()` internally.

The documentation for this method states the following:

> Save a transient object. An id is generated, assigned to the object and returned

*The `IRepository.Create()` method has a `void` return type so the new id is not returned, but it is assigned to the object which you pass to the method.*

**So in this case your `record` variable already contains the same object as you would get when querying the db.**